# Scope by User - Settings from Sales Cloud MC Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

community,

I would like to know what are the settings that need to be applied to the Sales/Service Cloud side to correctly use the functionalities of Scope by User regarding the connectivity between SFSC and SFMC and don't get any errors within JB or Email sends.

I can see that when "Scope by user" is selected in the Integration settings [MC], the user in MC needs to be "integrated" and then add the respective permission sets in SFSC.

Are there any other settings that need to be done like for example, when logged in with the user in SFSC, click on Connect to Marketing Cloud also?

[image]

Comment: You need to need to get your users to visit the Marketing Cloud tab to "Connect to Marketing Cloud" to pair their CRM user to the SFMC user or you can do it form them by clicking on the "Integrate" button on each SFMC user's profile and provide their corresponding CRM username. Be sure you want to use "Scope by User", though. Most user's wouldn't and it tends to confuse the heck out of matters unless your Sales Reps and the likes are the ones doing the sends and building the Journeys in SFMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanation of Scope by the user is If the account is configured as “scope by the user,” users view and send to only the records they own.
Now, comes to Connect to marketing Cloud Tab, this would need the user to assign the permission set for MCC package such Marketing Cloud for AppExchange Admin. In general, if the users just want to send the Email to give them the "Marketing Cloud for Appexchange User" permission set, this should be enough for them to send the emails to the records that they own or the records that they have access to.